# Text div goes down and slider goes up

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I am building a website. There is a section where two div sits beside one contains writings and another a slider. When I am viewing them on mobile devices, the writings stay on top and the slider bottom, but I want them in vice versa.

I have tried margin, negative margin, position in CSS but the fact is that the other section coming up which is unnecessary.

Here is the link of my website: http://fastfreelancebd.com/nicole/

I have added a picture. Also, the link. What result I want, I have described in summarization.
[Here is a screenshot of my site in the mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c4BB.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Use below CSS to do reverse div on mobile:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px)
.elementor-row {
   flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap 4, you can just add .flex-wrap-reverse to the parent container.